# iPhone fluid simulation (like in Liquid app, using gravity etc)

Tags: iphone, physics, fluid

How can i achieve Liquid app style fluid simulation? 
An I need LBM or SPH? I think SPH is too heavy for use on iPhone. But water in Liquid looks like SPH.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784745/iphone-fluid-simulation

Answer (score 0):

By now, probably you already have an answer for your question. Anyway, I think SPH is what Liquid lite uses. With good physics and some openGL tricks it could be done: i.e. in liquid lite when you tilt the phone, it seems the screen scales up instead of using gravity.
   Whatever you decide to do, my suggestion is that write everything in C (not C++) that will definitely boost your performance. And if you are using float-point operations (likely in a fluid simulation), turn the "Compile for thumb" OFF (that's an optimisation just for integer operations). It will give you about 15% more performance.

Hope it helps.