# Create liquid on Xcode for iPhone

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3

I'm looking for a code of how to create liquid for a iPhone app. There are some apps on the appStore with liquid like: Liquid lite, Liquid Dynamics, Ibeer, Where's my water.....
I need to create water, that I will move with the accelerometer. If someone can help will be more than great.
I saw there is a question like that here: [iPhone fluid simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784745/iphone-fluid-simulation) but the answer It is not good.