# Does anyone have a working example of fluid-animation code for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, animation, fluid

I'm looking for a sample iPhone app that includes animated fluids - for example, a fish tank, or glass of water. Is there one available somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone fluid simulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784745/iphone-fluid-simulation)

Comment: See also [How do I make a water effect view with openGLES on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726738/how-do-i-make-a-water-effect-view-with-opengles-on-the-iphone) and [How to implement water ripples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665076/how-to-implement-water-ripples)